# Firebase retrieve data from firebase into Html Table

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a solution for retrieving all the values of a node from firebase real time database into html table ? I want to show iot sensor data into html table from firebase? Every time when new value is added in humidity,Tempeature it goes into a new row in html table? How it is done?

```
 agrismart-c7cb0
 .
 .
     ---  ...Sensor
          ----- .Humidity
                 . -Ll1yRHBqZUSQUpAANYl: "64"
                 . -Ll1ySD9oG5fiia15eL0: "65"
                 . -Ll1yTrQnmS0T1ImusKQ: "68"
                 . -Ll1yVjd3wZi48jp9SB1: "65"
          ----- .Moisture
                 .  -LlQz7gIlHBKWT66T2gS: "96"
                 .  -LlQz80sa4qoOZvOSKPn: "95"
                 .  -LlQz8IlfBnlIy0FQZoM: "99"
                 .  -LlQz83LXAwr3FWqvmbN: "91"
          ----- .Temperature
                 . -Ll1yS8KchaePZcNypBG: "32"
                 . -Ll1yTmE4GM950mbXN0m: "33"
                 . -Ll1yVSn8vZ82UaPraSw: "36"
                 . -Ll1yX42I9gAWVm2B5yA: "38"
```

I have tried this code but i am getting only one row in HTML table, and it is displaying last child value of humidity, temperature, and moisture node. Console is showing all values but their is only one row in HTML table.

```
(function() {
    var dataHtml = '';
    var tableBody = document.getElementById('tabledata');

    var database = firebase.database();
    var humElement;
    var MoistElement;
    var tempElement;

    var humRef = database.ref('Sensor').child('Humidity');
    var MoistRef = database.ref('Sensor').child('Moisture');
    var tempRef = database.ref('Sensor').child('Temperature');

    humRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var childData1 = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log("humidity: " + childData1);
            humElement = childData1;
        });


        MoistRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var childData2 = childSnapshot.val();
                console.log("Moisture: " + childData2);
                MoistElement = childData2;

            });

            tempRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
                snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                    var childData3 = childSnapshot.val();
                    console.log("temperature: " + childData3);
                    tempElement = childData3;
                });

                $("#tabledata").append("<tr><td>" + humElement + "</td><td>" + MoistElement +
                    "</td><td>" + tempElement + "</td></tr>");
            });
        });
    });


}());
```

My html table code:

```
<table class="content-table" align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
<td >Humidity</td> 
<td >Moisture</td>
<td >Temperature</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tabledata">
</tbody>
</div>

</table>
```

My expected result is :

```
             Humidity | Moisture   | Temperature
               64     |     96     |    32
               65     |     95     |    33
               68     |     99     |    36 
               65     |     91     |    38
```

What i have retrieved yet

```
      Humidity    | Moisture   | Temperature
         65       |     91     |     38
```

What i am getting In console:

```
humidity:64
humidity:65
humidity:68
humidity:65
Moisture:96
Moisture:95
Moisture:99
Moisture:91
temperature:32
temperature:33
temperature:36
temperature:38
```

Could anyone tell me what i am doing wrong? Why i am not getting all values instad of last chlid value? Does anyone solve that problem.Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. What output did you expect to get in the console?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am expecting the same output in console which i am getting now,  but i am not getting the expected result on html table.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen all the child values of  Humidity, Moisture and Temperature nodes are printed on console whereas my html table is only getting last child values of these nodes. How can i show all values in html table?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you tell me what mistake i am doing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the problem should become a lot clearer if you add an extra log statement before the line where you add the data to the HTML:

```
humRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childData1 = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log("humidity: " + childData1);
        humElement = childData1;
    });


    MoistRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var childData2 = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log("Moisture: " + childData2);
            MoistElement = childData2;

        });

        tempRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var childData3 = childSnapshot.val();
                console.log("temperature: " + childData3);
                tempElement = childData3;
            });

            console.log("Adding "+humElement+", "+MoistElement+", "+tempElement+" to table");
            $("#tabledata").append("<tr><td>" + humElement + "</td><td>" + MoistElement +
                "</td><td>" + tempElement + "</td></tr>");
        });
    });
});
```

If you run this, the console will log:

```
humidity:64
humidity:65
humidity:68
humidity:65
Moisture:96
Moisture:95
Moisture:99
Moisture:91
temperature:32
temperature:33
temperature:36
temperature:38
Adding 65, 91, 38 to table
```

This is because you're first looping over each snapshot from the database, and extract a single value from each. Then once you've looped over all of them, you add the last value from each snapshot to the HTML.

Since you have three nested read operations, you also need to make sure the loops over the resulting data are nested:

```
humRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  MoistRef.once("value", function(snapshot2) {
    tempRef.once("value", function(snapshot3) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        humElement = childSnapshot.val();

        snapshot2.forEach(function(childSnapshot2) {
          MoistElement = childSnapshot2.val();

          snapshot3.forEach(function(childSnapshot3) {
            tempElement = childSnapshot3.val();

            $("#tabledata").append("<tr><td>" + humElement + "</td><td>" + MoistElement +
                "</td><td>" + tempElement + "</td></tr>");
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I created this updated JSBin to show how to get the latest value from each item and show it in the table: https://jsbin.com/sujuwik/edit?js,output

```
var dataHtml = '';
var tableBody = document.getElementById('tabledata');

var database = firebase.database();

var humRef = database.ref('Sensor').child('Humidity');
var moistRef = database.ref('Sensor').child('Moisture');
var tempRef = database.ref('Sensor').child('Tempratue');

humRef.limitToLast(1).once("value", function(snapshot) {
  moistRef.limitToLast(1).once("value", function(snapshot2) {
    tempRef.limitToLast(1).once("value", function(snapshot3) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        humElement = childSnapshot.val();
        snapshot2.forEach(function(childSnapshot2) {
          MoistElement = childSnapshot2.val();
          snapshot3.forEach(function(childSnapshot3) {
            tempElement = childSnapshot3.val();

            $("#tabledata").append("<tr><td>" + humElement + "</td><td>" + MoistElement +
                "</td><td>" + tempElement + "</td></tr>");
          }); // snapshot3.forEach
        }); // snapshot2.forEach
      }); // snapshot.forEach
    }); // tempRef...once()
  }); // moistRef...once()
}); // humRef...once()
```

As you can see, this uses `limitToLast(1)` to ensure we only get the latest item from each sensor, which makes it easy to align the data from each sensor.

If you want to show multiple rows, you'll need to figure out what reading from each sensor corresponds to what reading from the other sensors, since you have a different number of readings on each sensor (1312 humidity nodes, 1305 moisture nodes, 1314 temperature nodes).

For example: you could revert to using `on(...)` instead of `once(...)`, in which case the code will add a single row initially with the latest value from each sensor, and then add a new row whenever any of the sensors reports a new value.

Comment: I have tried this piece of code but it is not showing any values in html table.

Comment: I have also write console statments in that code, this code is repeating infinite times for temperature node in console.

Comment: There were some naming collisions in the code, and I just fixed them. If it doesn't work for you, try to understand what I changed about it. If it's not clear, ask about that. If it *is* clear, see what happens if you step through it in the debugger, and set breakpoints. What line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Still, this code is getting the same error, all the values are printed in console, whereas html table is displaying only last child of all nodes.

Comment: That sounds unexpected. Are you sure you're using my second snippet? If you set a breakpoint on the line `$("#tabledata").append(...)`, does it get hit? How often? What are the values of `humElement`, `MoistElement`, and `tempElement` when it gets hit? Can you reproduce the problem with this snippet in a site like jsbin, stackblitz or glitch?

Comment: My current project state of one row table:  https://jsbin.com/maliwesese/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: You changed the code much more than just adding `console.log`s there. You also close every enclosing block after you do a `console.log`, which is one of the things my code above fixes. The loop is also not infinite, but you just have a lot of nodes in your database (1312 humidity nodes, 1305 moisture nodes, 1314 temperature nodes). Since this code loops over all 3 and adds each combination to the table, that is 1312*1305*1314 rows, so there's a good chance the browser will have trouble holding that much HTML.

Comment: I get that you might want only one entry for what you consider each humidity, moisture, temperature combination (so roughly 1300 rows). But the data is not structured like that, so it's unclear what limit to apply to the data.

Comment: I've updated the JSBin to do the first 10 nodes of each, which leads to 10x10x10 combinations and thus 1000 rows in the table. But I'd really like you to focus on understanding the changes that I made to your code, because that is key to you being able to make progress on your own.

Comment: JSBIN is not changed yet, it is saved to previous state

Comment: is there any final solution to my given problem.Regardless to that  limitToLast(1) sinppet that you posted. Is this possoble to print all values in html table in their respective columns?

Comment: Is there an alternative solution for doing my task?