# Retrieve data from same level nodes from firebase in html table

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase real time database to html table. My database structure is:

```
 agrismart-c7cb0
 .
 .
     ---  ...Sensor
          ----- .Humidity
                 . -Ll1yRHBqZUSQUpAANYl: "64"
                 . -Ll1ySD9oG5fiia15eL0: "65"
                 . -Ll1yTrQnmS0T1ImusKQ: "68"
                 . -Ll1yVjd3wZi48jp9SB1: "65"
          ----- .Moisture
                 .  -LlQz7gIlHBKWT66T2gS: "96"
                 .  -LlQz80sa4qoOZvOSKPn: "95"
                 .  -LlQz8IlfBnlIy0FQZoM: "99"
                 .  -LlQz83LXAwr3FWqvmbN: "91"
          ----- .Temperature
                 . -Ll1yS8KchaePZcNypBG: "32"
                 . -Ll1yTmE4GM950mbXN0m: "33"
                 . -Ll1yVSn8vZ82UaPraSw: "36"
                 . -Ll1yX42I9gAWVm2B5yA: "38"
```

As Humidity, Temperature and Moisture nodes are in the same hierarchy in the Sensor node, i want to retrieve them in the html table.

I have retrieved humidity Node all values in html table. I have used following code for it:

```
var dataHtml = '';
var tableBody = document.getElementById('customers');

var database = firebase.database();
var rootRef = database.ref();
var urlRef = rootRef.child("Sensor/Humidity");

urlRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {

var Humid = child.val();

dataHtml += `<tr><td>${Humid}</td></tr>`;
tableBody.innerHTML = dataHtml;

});
});
```

But now i am having issues in retrieving moisture and temperature node values in table. I have used same code for both of them, and it is showing their values in Humidity column.

My expected result is :

```
         Humidity | Moisture   | Temperature
           64     |     96     |    32
           65     |     95     |    33
           68     |     99     |    36 
           65     |     91     |    38
```

What i have retrieved yet

```
         Humidity | Moisture   | Temperature
           64     |            |  
           65     |            |  
           68     |            |  
           65     |            |
```

Now i want to retrieve moisture and temperature node values, in the same table. But i am facing the problem that they are in the same hierarchy in the sensor node. Can anyone tell me the solution for this problem. I am facing this problem for very long time. Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is this different from the [question you posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586733/firebase-retrieve-data-from-firebase-into-html-table)?  If you have updates to that question, please click the edit link under it and don't open a new post.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have edited my last post, could you read that post and tell me what i am doing wrong with my html table?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the Sensor node and arrange the values for humidity, moisture and and temperature Programatically.

`var urlRef = rootRef.child("Sensor");
 urlRef.once('value',(snap)=>{
 console.log(snap.val());
})`